# employement verification issues would i still get the job?

Tags: background-check

I need help! im freakinggg out. I recently got offered a positon and when they did a background check of my employment there was a small discrepancy. They did verify I worked there but the dates were off and when he called me I verified the dates they told him and explained it was a typo do to edits on my resume. Does that mean I cannot have the position now?! :(

Comment: How different were the dates?  What was the correct range, and what did you have down?  If it's a relatively small difference, you probably won't have a problem.  Whatever you do, stay calm when discussing this with the company.  Freaking out on them will be a bigger red flag than a small date discrepancy.

Comment: If we're talking a few weeks it's unlikely to be an issue. If we're talking 2 years it almost certainly will be. If it's more than a couple of months then it likely depends on the situation - a mistake of a month or two regarding a 5-year employment you left 6 years ago is less of an issue than a 6 month gap last year. Chances are that unless the mistake is bad enough to appear deliberately dishonest, and unless the mistake materially changes your experience level (ie adds experience), it's unlikely to cause any serious issues.

Answer (score 3):

> Does that mean I cannot have the position now?

Almost certainly it doesn't mean that.

Mistakes happen. Typos happen. Hiring companies understand that.

As long as this was just an honest mistake and nothing more nefarious, I wouldn't be worried.